# Public assets in vendor package in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to be able to access the assets of a package in the vendor folder from my views without success.

I have tried to put the package in the AppServiceProvider and then publish it but not works.

Any ideas?

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome' => public_path('css/font-awesome')
        ], 'font-awesome');
    }
}
```

`php artisan vendor:publish`

Comment: I think that's intended to be used when you develop a package targetting Laravel. For example you can create your own package that depends on `fortawesome/font-awesome` (which sidenote I have no idea how you managed to get into `vendor` since it's not a composer package) and then in your package add a service provider that publishes that css. Then anyone (including you) who depends on your package can run that command. However since font-awesome is an NPM package you should probably use [laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should easily be able to publish vendor content by using the command:

> php artisan vendor:publish

You will then be promted a list of packages (tags) to choose from, simply type the number that corresponds to the desired package, then choose the files you want to publish.

For this to work of course, the package it self needs to publish the files in their service provider.

If the package doesn't publish them, then you can simply manually copy the desired files into your public directory (or whereever you want them to be).